# ORA-29285: file write error

Tags: oracle, export, utl-file

I'm trying to extract data from an Oracle table. I'm using utl file for that and I'm receiving the error ORA-29285: file write error. The weird here is if I try extract the data directly from the table return the error, if I extract the data using a simple view the error is returned as well, BUT if I extract the data using a view with an ORDER BY the extraction is well succeed. I can't understand where the error is, I already look for the length of lines and nothing. Any suggestion from which can be?

I extract a lot of other data through the utl_file and I'm well succed. This data in specific is at the first time uploaded to Oracle table directly from a csv file with ANSI encoding. However I have other data uploaded by the same way and then I can export correctly. I checked the encoding too in order to reduce the possible mistakes and I found nothing.

Many thanks,
Priscila Ferreira

Comment: add a piece of your code .